# What is the difference, if there is one, between the tags "design" and "so-design"?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

I noticed there are two tags that seem similar: [design](/questions/tagged/design), and [so-design](/questions/tagged/so-design).

Do they have two different purposes, or should we use [design](/questions/tagged/design) in both cases, and eventually add [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) to questions that are currently using [so-design](/questions/tagged/so-design)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no questions using [so-design](/questions/tagged/so-design) anymore. I guess the tag has been merged with [design](/questions/tagged/design), or it has been removed from the questions using it.

Anyway, the message seems that we didn't need [so-design](/questions/tagged/so-design). `:)`